# JNI - library loads successfully but native methods do not work

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have no problem loading my dll and even breaking in my c code by attaching my java process in visual studio. However, when a native method gets called in my java code, it is seemingly skipped and the java program continues to execute. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the code hits in visual studio, have you tried stepping through it? Also, is it supposed to return something.

Comment: I can step through my JNI_OnLoad function where I get all my methods and fields and cache them. After the load function completes, my java code continues to my constructer which initiates a native method call. This call has a long type return value, however the function in java side always returns with a 0 even though it has not hit my breakpoints in my native method. I am confused on how it is apparently executing the function without it hitting my breakpoint.

Comment: You should provide some minimal code reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am more just looking for some ideas on what could be going wrong so I have something to look at. If my library loads but my native methods aren't running when they are called there is obviously a disconnect, I am just looking for some ideas on what that disconnect could be.

Comment: If your native methods aren't running there is an exception that tells you why. Usually it is a mismatch between the native method signature and the signature used in the C code. JNI code requires error checking  after every JNI API invocation. Don't skimp it.